# SQL function for converting string expression to proper value

Tags: sql-server, function, sql-server-2014

I need a function to convert mathematical expressions to a float value:

```
create function dbo.ExpressionToValue
(
     @expression nvarchar(max)
)
returns float as 
begin
     declare @result float 
     --convertion codes 
     return @result
end
```

expected usage:

```
select dbo.ExpressionToValue('2+3')
```

expected result:

```
5
```

Comment: Why not just call it in the select?

Comment: I want to use it inside a view and some other usages. I keep formulas in a column of table

Comment: It still doesn't make sense to do since you'll have to call it every time and in every place that you could just explicitly convert it. It's not worth the performance drop. But at any rate, what are you wanting more than `set @results = convert(float, @expression)`?

Comment: I just noticed you are passing in a varchar.... so this likely isn't the route you want to go since the expressions are going to be endless

Comment: Please try your proposed code in function and see the result.

Comment: You need dynamic sql which isn't available in a function, but can be used in a SP

Answer (score 0):

An alternative hack is to leverage C# in the form of an assembly. C# does not have an eval function, but this too can be hacked.

You can create an assembly function like

```
using System.Data.DataTable
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{


    [SqlFunction()]
    public static double eval(string expression)
    {

      System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
      return Convert.ToDouble(table.Compute(expression, String.Empty)); 


    }
}
```

Build the assembly using VisualStudio and then
register the assembly.  One word of caution is that you might have to compile down to a lower version of the .NET framework depending on which one is supported by your current version of SQL server.

You can register your assembly in SQL Server using the procedure described on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k(v=vs.100).aspx