# How to use variable and changing user defined functions in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, sql-server-2014, user-defined-functions

I have defined some user defined function in sql server . for example :

`select dbo.SumItems(1 , 2)` will return `3`

and

`select dbo.MaxItems(5 , 3)` will return `5`

and some other functions may be more complicated.
also I keep variables and their formula expressions in a table:

```
IdVar Title Formula 
----- ----- ---------------------
1     Sum   dbo.SumItems(@a , @b)
2     Max   dbo.maxItems(@a , @b)
```

I have my parameters in another table :

```
a   b
--  --
1   2
5   3
```

now i want to join this two tables and get the following result :

```
Parameter a   Parameter b  Variable Title  Result
-----------   -----------  --------------  ------
1             2            Sum             3
1             2            Max             2
5             3            Sum             8
5             3            Max             5
```

also I have asked my problem from another view [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40984068/sql-function-for-converting-string-expression-to-proper-value).

Comment: SQL queries are not designed to do this.  This is one case where a cursor might be the best approach.

Comment: cursor? can you explain more?

Comment: Is this a *real-world* need? What are you trying to achieve? I'm pretty sure, that there are better ways for this...

Comment: yes Its a real need , i am developing a data analysis software and i need to calculate many variables using user defined functions.

Comment: @Shnugo As I suspected this was real-world.  I've done something very similar to dynamically calculate a series of financial ratios for numerous LOBs in one pass.

Answer (score 1):

Posted something very similar to this yesterday.  As you know, you can only perform such function with dynamic sql.

Now, I don't have your functions, so you will have to supply those.

I've done something very similar in the past to calculate a series of ratios in one pass for numerous income/balance sheets

Below is one approach.  (However, I'm not digging the 2 parameters ... seems a little limited, but I'm sure you can expand as necessary)

```
Declare @Formula table (ID int,Title varchar(25),Formula varchar(max))
Insert Into @Formula values
 (1,'Sum'     ,'@a+@b')
,(2,'Multiply','@a*@b')

Declare @Parameter table (a varchar(50),b varchar(50))
Insert Into @Parameter values
(1,2),
(5,3)

Declare @SQL varchar(max)=''
;with cte as (
Select A.ID
      ,A.Title
      ,ParameterA = A
      ,ParameterB = B
      ,Expression = Replace(Replace(Formula,'@a',a),'@b',b)
 From  @Formula A 
 Cross Join @Parameter B
)
Select  @SQL = @SQL+concat(',(',ID,',',ParameterA,',',ParameterB,',''',Title,''',(',Expression,'))') From cte 
Select  @SQL = 'Select * From ('+Stuff(@SQL,1,1,'values')+') N(ID,ParameterA,ParameterB,Title,Value)'
Exec(@SQL)

-- Optional To Trap Results in a Table Variable 
--Declare @Results table (ID int,ParameterA varchar(50),ParameterB varchar(50),Title varchar(50),Value float)
--Insert Into @Results Exec(@SQL)
--Select * from @Results
```

Returns

```
ID  ParameterA  ParameterB  Title      Value
1   1           2           Sum         3
2   1           2           Multiply    2
1   5           3           Sum         8
2   5           3           Multiply    15
```